# HttpClient not throwing after lost connection

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Windows Store application in which I need to download a file a couple of megabytes in size.

I am trying to do this using the HttpClient.

Here is a simplification of the code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request =
    await httpClient.SendAsync(
        new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Get,
        "http://openpandora.info:8080/Battlefield%204%20-%20Fishing%20in%20Baku%20-%20Xbox%20One.mp4"),
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    var outputFile =
    await
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        "test.data",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var outputStream = await outputFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await request.Content.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
    }
}
```

The sample code provided here is downloading a 2GB file for illustration purposes.

The issue is the following. If the client has no internet connection when the app is started, the code throws an exception as expected. However, if the client loses internet connectivity while the download is running no exception is thrown and the code will never execute beyond the code block. If the client encounters no connection problems during download, the code works fine.

Any insight on why this is the case?

Comment: How long are you waiting for the exception to be thrown?

Comment: Doesn't `HttpClient` have a Timeout property?

Comment: @Stephen I have tried waiting well beyond 20 minutes

Comment: @Dan Yes, and I have tried setting the timeout to a very small value. It seems the timeout is not honored after the stream has started downloading

Comment: @DEHAAS That is correct.  When you use ResponseHeadersRead the Cancellation token and timer are disposed as soon as the headers have been read.  It is up to you to do your own timeout if you are copying the stream manually.