# HttpClient.GetAsync(...) "deadlock" when there is no internet connection

Tags: c#, async-await, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

Recenly I found some sort of bug while using **System.Net.http.HttpClient().GetAsync(...)**

When in the middle process of **GetAsync(..)**, if I disconnect my internet connection, the app just act like deadlock, and no exception catch, even I wait for few minutes.

***Here is the example of code:***

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> loadImageAsync(string url)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        //When this line of code start execute, immediately disable the internet connection
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        //Once it get stuck at GetAsync(..), it won't execute the codes below
        byte[] imageByte = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1920, 1080);

        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomStream))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes(imageByte);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                await writer.FlushAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
            }

            randomStream.Seek(0);

            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(randomStream);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

I had try to set timeout to the httpClient, but it won't care what I set if there is no internet connection.

Is there any way to catch if the internet connection is disconnected, or did I miss something?

**Edit:** another async task that await loadImageAsync(..)

```
public async Task GetImagesAsync()
{
    //skip if image is currently loading
    if (IsImageLoading) { return; }

    IsImageLoading = true;
    ImageObjs.Clear();

    try
    {
        int numberOfLoad = (int)((double)_LocalSettings.Values[NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_LOAD_SETTINGS]);
        string region = _LocalSettings.Values[REGION].ToString();

        #region Get Bing Image info
        string jsonString = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync($"http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&n={numberOfLoad}&mkt={region}");
        ImageCollection imageCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageCollection>(jsonString);
        #endregion

        #region Download images
        foreach (var i in imageCollection.images)
        {
            string url;

            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
            {
                url = i.url.Replace("1920x1080", "1080x1920");
            }
            else
            {
                url = i.url;
            }

            ImageObjs.Add(new ImageObj(await loadImageAsync(bingLink + url), i.copyright, url, i.copyrightlink, region));
        }

        showToastNotification(_MainViewModel.ImageObjs.Count.ToString() + " images loaded.");
        #endregion
    }
    catch
    {
        //if connection failed
    }
    finally
    {
        IsImageLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `Wait` or `Result` anywhere further up the call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary I just add the async task code in my question that await the loadImageAsync(..)

Comment: And you're not calling `.Result` or `.Wait` or similar, **any** place up the callstack?

Comment: @StephenCleary But I did find out something strange, I download my app from the store (with the same code logic), everything works fine, but if I sideload the same package that on the store, deadlock happen...I tried on other device including Phone, all have the same issue.

Comment: @StephenCleary There is question post by someone, I have the exactly same issue with him. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335373/httpclient-not-throwing-after-lost-connection?rq=1)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, I didn't calling any of `.Result` or `.Wait`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? - I too face the issue.

Comment: I just ran into this while testing connectivity with no adapter enabled; solved it by wrapping `response = await httpClient.GetAsync()` call in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting timeout with CancelationToken?

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

try
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, tokenSource.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // handle timeout here
}
```

Comment: Nothing change, still the same =(